# Why does foreach throw an exception if collection is null

Tags: c#, foreach, nullreferenceexception

I'm asking what is the reasoning for throwing an exception when the object that you are trying to iterate over with a foreach loop is null?

For example, the following code throws an exception:

```
public void Test()
{
    IEnumerable<int> numbers = null;

    foreach (var number in numbers)
    {
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

Now the fix is easy enough, just check for null before the foreach loop.

```
public void Test()
{
    IEnumerable<int> numbers = null;

    if (numbers != null)
    {
        foreach (var number in numbers)
        {
            //Do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

My thoughts are, everything you can do with a foreach loop, you can do with just a regular for loop and therefor the foreach loop basically exists because it is more convenient to write and easier to read. The important part is that is it more convenient to write. If something is created to be convenient, why not go all the way and in this case do the null check implicitly. Now there may be a some cases where you would actually want an exception to be thrown if the collection is null however, I feel that those are in the minority by far and they should be the cases where you need to be explicit and check for null. Something like the following:

```
public static void Test()
{
    IEnumerable<int> numbers = null;

    if (numbers == null)
        throw new NullReferenceException();

    foreach (var number in numbers)
    {
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: There really is no correct answer to this question.  "Why is the feature this way?" type of questions can't really be answered.  That being said, if you're goal is to enumerate a collection, and the collection is null, I'd expect an exception.  The same happens with a for loop (as soon as you'd access the Count/Length properties).  I'd argue that the cases when you want the exception are in the far majority, not the minority.

Comment: First of all, this question is primarily about opinions, and so should be closed. Second of all, our opinions are not very important at this late stage of the development of the language, as this is how it has been since Day 1.

Comment: @Tom: `null` exists to serve a specific purpose: indicating "no data". By ignoring null as you suggest, you violate this purpose.

Comment: I think it's much better than hiding possible programming error (I consider null a coding error in many cases and use ReSharpers `[NotNull]` all over ;-). It's easy to use a construct like `foreach (var b in blah ?? Enumerable.Empty<B>()) { .. }`, if that semantic is required.

Comment: @SimpleCoder: I'd bet that was part of the reasoning, too.  (Aside from implementation concerns.)  `null` is different from an empty collection, and should behave differently.  The last time I asked a question about "why doesn't C# do this" Eric Lippert gave a really good answer.  He basically said, "Instead of asking why we didn't do that, ask what compelling reason we would have had to make the effort to do that."  Under other constraints and deadlines, if there's no compelling reason to do something (and, indeed, compelling reasons not to) then it won't be done.

Comment: @SimpleCoder I agree, and this was the closest I could come to the reason for the exception to be thrown but at the end of the day I still feel the the foreach loop is primarily for convenience and therefore should imply the null check, not ignore the null case.

Comment: @David That is interesting but in this case, the the reason to do the null check implicitly would be for convenience which, to my knowledge, is the reason for the foreach in first place.

Comment: @Tom: Which is a matter of opinion.  I'd personally find it terribly inconvenient if I had to check for `null` when I wanted to explicitly avoid it, rather than just let the method throw an exception and handle it elsewhere.  If it silently failed, I'd have to add `null` checks everywhere to look for error conditions that would otherwise make themselves known.  All things being equal, it's better for the compiler not to do too much thinking for the developer.

Comment: Also, can we remove the hold on this question for being opinion-based? The question was not "Do you think the foreach loop should throw an exception" it was "What is the reasoning for the foreach loop throwing an exception" to which there should be only one correct answer. In my opinion :P

Comment: @Tom: Keep in mind also the implications of what you're proposing. You're sort of suggesting that "a `null` reference on an `IEnumerable` should behave similarly to an empty enumeration." You've identified a much more specific example, but that's basically the gist of it. Which would mean that `null` references to *some* reference types behave differently than `null` references to *other* reference types. Should a `null` reference to some custom type (say a `Customer` class) act like an empty instance of that class? Clearly not. (At least not in C#.) I'm reaching, but you get the idea.

Comment: @Tom, the question should absolutely be "on hold".  To me it's opinion-based -- you are just asking for the opinions of the original design team.  Regardless, it is a wholly inappropriate question for this site.

Comment: @Tom: The problem with this question (and what makes it opinion based) is that you are asking *why* in the context of your specific use case. You'd like to treat null and an empty List as the same thing, but most people don't want this.

Comment: Again, I'm not saying that null and empty list should be treated as the same, not at all. All I am saying is that there could be a null check that is implied in the same way that the call to GetEnumerator is implied. That null check isn't implied and instead a NullReferenceException is thrown. All I was asking for is a justification of why the null check can't be implied and the why the  throwing of a NullReferenceException is indeed the right choice. This is not about opinions. There is a correct answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IMO, throwing an exception in this scenario is a good thing. Otherwise, you risk forgetting to initialize your `IEnumerable` and running your code as though everything is fine (when in fact it's not iterating over your list like you want). In most programs, this mistake would quickly become obvious, but better to have your program crash than to risk it silently malfunctioning.

For example, pretend the following code regulates the nuclear power plant three miles down the road from where you live:

```
while (true)
{
    List<string> coresThatAreOverheating = getOverheatingCores();
    foreach (string thisCore in coresThatAreOverheating)
    {
        coolCoreDown(thisCore);
    }
}
```

Now consider if there was a bug in `getOverheatingCores()` that caused it to occasionally return `null`. Under my preference of throwing an exception on the `foreach`, you'll very likely discover that during software development. Under your preference of silently treating `null` like an empty list, you'll discover that when there's a nuclear meltdown. Don't know about you, but I know which one I like better :)

Comment: Agreed.  Noisy one-time full-stop failures are better than silent ongoing unnoticed failures.

Comment: Can you give an example of when the null case can't be handled the same as the empty collection case because it would lead to an unexpected result? This is assuming that the foreach loop doesn't throw and exception in the null case.

Comment: @Tom: edited my answer to include an example.

Comment: That is a really good example. Thanks for taking the time to come up with it because I will remember it now every time I surround my foreach loops with a null check.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped. The only time you should do a `null` check like that is when the code that you yourself wrote might have set the list to `null`. Otherwise, don't artificially sweep unexpected errors under the rug with such a check. Instead, let the exception be thrown; if it crashes your program, consider that a good thing (better than a nuclear disaster, right? :)

Answer (score 4):

No.. a `foreach` is turned into an enumerator.. essentially, a `foreach` on `numbers` does this:

```
var enumerator = numbers.GetEnumerator();
```

..like any other call, a method call on a `null` reference throws a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: Note that this doesn't really answer the question, though - the null check *could* have been added, and this call avoided.  (That being said, there is no real way to answer this question...)

Comment: I upvoted you, but to be the devil's advocate, since the enumerator appears from a construct of the compiler, there really could be a check for nullity that returns an empty enumerator.

Comment: Its true.. but hopefully it points out to the OP what is actually happening here.. not that it's just a random nullref.

Comment: Yup, I know what is happening under the hood. That wasn't the question though. The question was why it can't do the null check for me for convenience? What is the reasoning?

Comment: @Tom Because "that is how it was defined". It's not that it *couldn't* have been; it's simply that it is *not* how it is.

Comment: I fear for the day when the compiler spoon feeds you like that.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I'll be really happy for the day when I never have to see another `null` :> That being said, there *are* languages that will treat "nothing" like an empty list. LISP-ish languages with `nil` is a trivial example.

Comment: @user2246674: You might be interested in this presentation: http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Null-References-The-Billion-Dollar-Mistake-Tony-Hoare

Comment: @David Oh, I *totally* agree - I would love a `T!` (non-nullable reference-type T, pretty much the opposite of `S?`; and syntax to help with guard conversions/usage) to be added to C# :>

Comment: @user2246674 to your "that is how it was defined" comment. Using the way something is to justify the way it aught to be is a fallacy.

Comment: @Tom I don't agree here. The question asked was *why does*, not *what are [some] reasons for..* The first is a quick glance at the specification, the latter opens up looking into the rational for such a specification. (Unfortunately it also opens up a what-if can of worms that is often considered subjective without an [known] authoritative source which can be hard to find.)